# Right using of mapping in WebFlux

Tags: java, mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-reactive

```
public Mono<EmailDto> getEmail() {
Mono<EmailService> emailService = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .map(securityContext -> (Principal) securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal())
                    .map(principal -> emailServiceSelector.selectSuitable(principal.getInfo()));

return emailService.map(service -> service.findInfoByEmail(dto.getManagerEmail())) }
```

But I have a problem with this method, because  `emailService.map(service -> service.findInfoByEmail(dto.getManagerEmail()))` returns `Mono<Mono<EmailDto>>`.
Implementation of `findInfoByEmail(String email)` is

```
public Mono<EmailDto> findInfoByEmail(String email) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri(emailServiceProperties.getUrl(), email)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(EmailDto.class);
}
```

My method returns `Mono<EmailDto>`, not `Mono<Mono<EmailDto>>`.
So, my question is:
How to tranform `Mono<Mono<EmailDto>>` to `Mono<EmailDto>`? Or mb I am totally wrong and method should return `Mono<Mono<EmailDto>>`? Looking forward to any help.

Comment: If you have a `Mono` and another `Mono` you need to pass control to then use `Mono::flatMap`.

Comment: @Vladimir any updates on this? Did you try out the answer?

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty yes, ty very much. It's exactly what I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a **difference** between a flatmap and map.
*flatMap* should be used for **non-blocking** operations, or in short anything which returns back Mono,Flux.
*map* should be used when you want to do the transformation of an object /data in fixed time. The operations which are done **synchronously**.

Your `findInfoByEmail` is making an async call.

Thus you should use:

```
return emailService.flatMap(service -> service.findInfoByEmail(dto.getManagerEmail())) }
```

This is from the official [doc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html)

[image: flatmap]
[image: map]

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right but you need to use flatMap() in place of map().
map is used to transform the particular object into other where as flatMap() is used to transform all 1 to N objects into Mono in you case.
So you can use below snippet:-

return emailService.flatMap(service -> service.findInfoByEmail(dto.getManagerEmail())) }